# PHP mixed array for each

Tags: php, arrays

I can't get the output of my array as I want.

**Array:**

Array ( [0] => Fotoğraf & Video:Online Video [1] => Fotoğraf & Video:Dijital Dosyalar [2] => Çekim Çeşitleri:Yüzük Çekimleri [3] => Çekim Çeşitleri:Evlilik Çekimleri )

**Output:** (Foreach)

**Fotoğraf & Video** Online Video

**Fotoğraf & Video** Dijital Dosyalar

**Çekim Çeşitleri** Yüzük Çekimleri

**Çekim Çeşitleri**  Evlilik Çekimleri

**The output I want**

**Fotoğraf & Video**
Online Video,Dijital Dosyalar

**Çekim Çeşitleri**
Evlilik Çekimleri,Yüzük Çekimleri

*I'm waiting for your help. Thank you*

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes I read and edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = [
 'test: apple',
 'test: banana',
 'test2: pear',
 'test2: grape',
];

$newData = [];

foreach ($data as $d) {
    // separate string into two pieces
    $parts = explode(':', $d);
    $leftPart = $parts[0];
    $rightPart = $parts[1];

    // add new data to new array
    $newData[$leftPart][] = $rightPart;
}

$resultData = [];

foreach ($newData as $word => $nd) {
    // take data from new array and combine it into string
    $resultData[$word] = implode(',', $nd);
}

print_r($resultData); // see what's in array

// Or if you want to display, like you described, do this:

foreach ($resultData as $key => $value) {
   echo '<b>'.$key.'</b> '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Here's the answer. You are perfect. Thank you for your help. Great

Answer (score 0):

Just cycle through your array and use explode:

```
foreach ($input as $value) {
    $parts = explode(":", $value);
    echo '<span style="font-weight: bold;">'.$parts[0].':</span> '.$parts[1];
}
```